# Template deduction guide for std::vector: qualified/non-qualified names for other std types

Tags: c++, templates, stdvector, c++17

From [cppreference:s deduction guides for `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/deduction_guides), the following deduction guide is presented:

> ```
> template< class InputIt,
>           class Alloc = std::allocator<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>>
> vector(InputIt, InputIt, Alloc = Alloc())
>   -> vector<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type, Alloc>;
> ```

Where (as also mentioned in the [discussion of the page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:cpp/container/vector/deduction_guides)) `vector` does not include its namespace qualifier, which I interpret follows from clauses 1 and 3 from [17.10 (temp.deduct.guide)](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide):

> 1 ... Deduction guides are not found by name lookup.
>
> 3 ... A deduction-guide shall be declared in the same scope as the corresponding class template and, for a member class template, with
>   the same access.

I wonder about whether the qualified names, used for e.g. `std::allocator` in the template parametrization, and for `std::iterator_traits` in the simple-template-id, are strictly necessary. From the quoted part of 3 above, mustn't the deduction guide be declared within `namespace std`, as `vector` is?

**Question(s)**

- Is it necessary to use qualified names as in the deduction guide for `std::vector` above, when these should be available via unqualified lookup (same scope as the deduction guide)?
- If *"no"*, what would be the foremost motivation to use the qualified name(s)?

Comment: For cppreference? The primary motivation is to get the links to work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no special name lookup rule for deduction guides, and therefore no requirement to use qualified names if unqualified lookup would find the name. In fact, the deduction guide in the [standard itself](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/vector.overview#2) uses unqualified names:

```
namespace std {

  // [...]

  template<class InputIterator,
           class Allocator = allocator<typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>>
    vector(InputIterator, InputIterator, Allocator = Allocator())
      -> vector<typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, Allocator>;

  // [...]

}
```

The practice of cppreference is to use qualified names whenever allowed, but this is a stylistic choice to improve the clarity of presentation, minimize ambiguities, and play nicely with our linking infrastructure.

---

<sub>Note that the grammar of [deduction guides](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.guide#nt:deduction-guide) requires a *template-name* before the `(` and a *simple-template-id* after the `->`. Neither permits qualification. Another common example of unqualified names is when we want to refer to the injected-class-name of a class (template).</sub>